# Different alignment required for different resolutions in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, view

I am publishing a site using bootstrap 3. I'd like to center align the site logo for mobile view where as it must remained left aligned on all other devices. Is there any possible way to handle this issue I am totally stuck.

```
<div class="header_cont">
<div class="container">
    <header class="row header">
        <h1 class="logo col-lg-7 col-md-7"><a href="index.html">Property Ad</a></h1>
        <div class="sign_up_section col-md-5 col-lg-5 pull-right">
            <div class="social_links">...</div><!--social_links -->
            <div class="sign_up_links">...</div><!--sign_up_links -->
        </div><!--sign_up_section -->
    </header><!--header -->
</div>
```

Comment: Look into `push` and `pull` in Bootstrap.

Comment: You can't use both "col-lg-7" AND "col-md-7". Same goes for "col-md-5" and "col-lg-5".

Comment: ok thanks for your feedback but do you have any idea how to handle various alignments of contents for different screen views with in a same div?